# How can I send emails from my app "locally"?

Tags: windows-xp, email, localhost, smtp

I have an app that sends emails and I want to test it under high volumes of traffic (not because it needs to send high volumes of emails - because I'm debugging a problem that occurs rarely and is related to the sending of emails).  I want to send emails from the app, but via a SMTP server local to my development PC (so I don't look like a spammer), and preferably *to* a local destination, so that I'm not using tons of internet traffic.

What's the best (free) way to do this (Win XP SP3)?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed off topic as it doesn't seem to be.  Anyway, here is a free email server you can run locally: http://www.hmailserver.com/

Comment: Thanks Paul.  @Random,  I'd be interested to know of a better Stack Exchange forum for this question.  Reading the FAQ, it seems to fit the requirements.

Comment: I agree with Paul. I've used [testmailer](http://download.cnet.com/TestMailer/3000-2381_4-10510511.html) and it works well for me. It runs completely local -- no Internet connection required.